# Microsoft Translate Voice limit 200-400 words when request

Tags: javascript

I have a URL of Microsoft Translate Voice to get voice look like:

```html
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="https://www.bing.com/tspeak?&format=audio%2Fmp3&language=en&IG=D2CBB80AA6824D9A91B0A5D1074FC4A1&IID=translator.5034.2&text=I’m Often at the End of My Rope as a Mom of Two" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

The problem is: `text="any text here"`. `Any text here` is limit about 200-400 word. I don't know the reason at here. In [Bing Translate](https://www.bing.com/translator) I can insert full 5000 words and click button audio to hear.

Have any method to pass this problem? Microsoft is limit in this URL?

Have any method to insert 5000 words like Microsoft Translate homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open your developer console on Bing's website and start playing the sound, you'll see it sends a first mp3 request with only a couple of words, and when it's done reading it, it sends another one, and so on.

You could do the same:

```js
// When the DOM (basically the HTML) is loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    // Define your DOM elements
    var getAudioBtn = document.getElementById('getAudioBtn'),
        langSelect = document.getElementById("langSelect"),
        langSource = document.getElementById("langSource"),
        audioEl = document.getElementById('audioEl');

    // Setup an event listener on the button
    getAudioBtn.addEventListener('click', getContentTranslate);
    // Setup an listener on the audio onended event
    audioEl.addEventListener('ended', readChunkQueue);
    
    var chunkQueue = [], // Queue of chunks of text to read
        wordsPerChunk = 80, // Words per chunk
        language = 'en'; // Default language

    function getContentTranslate() {
        // Store the language
        language = langSelect.value;
        
        // Empty the chunks array
        chunkQueue = [];
        // Split the text into words
        var words = langSource.value.split(/ /g),
            tmp = []; // Temporary array for creating a chunk
        
        while(words.length) {
            // If out temporary chunk is full, add it to the list
            if (tmp.length === wordsPerChunk) {
                chunkQueue.push(tmp.join(' '));
                tmp = [];
            }
            tmp.push(words.shift());
        }
        if (tmp.length) {
            chunkQueue.push(tmp.join(' '));
        }

        // Start reading these chunks
        readChunkQueue();
    }
    
    function readChunkQueue() {
      // If the list is empty, stop
      if (!chunkQueue.length) {
        return;
      }
      // Get the first chunk in the list
      var chunk = chunkQueue.shift(),
          url = 'https://www.bing.com/tspeak?&format=audio%2Fmp3'
              + '&language=' + encodeURIComponent(language)
              + '&IG=D2CBB80AA6824D9A91B0A5D1074FC4A1&IID=translator.5034.2'
              + '&text=' + encodeURIComponent(chunk);
      // Set the URL as source for the audio element
      audioEl.setAttribute('src', url);
    }
});
```

```html
<select id="langSelect">
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="vi">Vietnamese</option>
</select>
<br>
<textarea id="langSource" placeholder="Enter text or webpage URL here">Obama Inaugural Address. 20th January 2009. My fellow citizens: I stand here today humbled by the task before us, grateful for the trust you have bestowed, mindful of the sacrifices borne by our ancestors. I thank President Bush for his service to our nation, as well as the generosity and cooperation he has shown throughout this transition. Forty-four Americans have now taken the presidential oath. The words have been spoken during rising tides of prosperity and the still waters of peace. Yet, every so often the oath is taken amidst gathering clouds and raging storms. At these moments, America has carried on not simply because of the skill or vision of those in high office, but because We the People have remained faithful to the ideals of our forbearers, and true to our founding documents. So it has been. So it must be with this generation of Americans. That we are in the midst of crisis is now well understood. Our nation is at war, against a far-reaching network of violence and hatred. Our economy is badly weakened, a consequence of greed and irresponsibility on the part of some, but also our collective failure to make hard choices and prepare the nation for a new age. Homes have been lost; jobs shed; businesses shuttered. Our health care is too costly; our schools fail too many; and each day brings further evidence that the ways we use energy strengthen our adversaries and threaten our planet. These are the indicators of crisis, subject to data and statistics. Less measurable but no less profound is a sapping of confidence across our land - a nagging fear that America's decline is inevitable, and that the next generation must lower its sights. Today I say to you that the challenges we face are real. They are serious and they are many. They will not be met easily or in a short span of time. But know this, America - they will be met. On this day, we gather because we have chosen hope over fear, unity of purpose over conflict and discord. On this day, we come to proclaim an end to the petty grievances and false promises, the recriminations and worn out dogmas, that for far too long have strangled our politics. We remain a young nation, but in the words of Scripture, the time has come to set aside childish things. The time has come to reaffirm our enduring spirit; to choose our better history; to carry forward that precious gift, that noble idea, passed on from generation to generation: the God-given promise that all are equal, all are free, and all deserve a chance to pursue their full measure of happiness. In reaffirming the greatness of our nation, we understand that greatness is never a given. It must be earned. Our journey has never been one of short-cuts or settling for less. It has not been the path for the faint-hearted - for those who prefer leisure over work, or seek only the pleasures of riches and fame. Rather, it has been the risk-takers, the doers, the makers of things - some celebrated but more often men and women obscure in their labor, who have carried us up the long, rugged path towards prosperity and freedom.</textarea>
<br>
<button id="getAudioBtn">GET AUDIO</button>
<br>
<audio id="audioEl" autoplay controls></audio>
```

Comment: You very pro. Instead of only have one sentence like your example. I want about three sentence or 80 words it will break and continues read. Can you add more code to this case? I don't have many experiences with Javascript. But I found your knowledge is very broad

Comment: And my main purpose is get only one file mp3 for a paragraph. If like this. Have many file mp3 and it auto change. Have any method to get all mp3(like join all file) to one file mp3?

Comment: @vanloc I've edited my answer to read the text in chunks of 80 words. Unfortunately, I don't think you can get a single MP3 file for very long texts. This URL you are using is not made for that. You could either send the mp3's to a server and merge them together there, or use the real, public [Bing text to speech API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/bingvoiceoutput), which might allow that (But the free trial may have some limits, you may have to pay to send more requests than what's allowed on the free plan)

Comment: I found a lib Github can merge multiple mp3 files. https://github.com/jackedgson/crunker. Can you see it and create a sample code for my case? Thanks for your helping.

Comment: @vanloc I'm sorry I don't have time to try this right now

Comment: I only have the final question. I run your code on a real project.
You can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/32x7c2q8/
I don't know why it doesn't autoplay next audio. I tried to write like your example. The difference in event `dom load` to event waiting for user click button.

Comment: @vanloc You simply forgot to add an event listener for the audio `onended` event :) https://jsfiddle.net/32x7c2q8/1/

Comment: I found I very stupid. Thanks for your answer. You're awesome!

Comment: @vanloc Thanks for your multiple upvotes, but that's illegal, StackOverflow will cancel these votes and may flag your account

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will only upvote any question and answer is good.

Comment: Hi @blex. Seem JS code only working on the browser of Desktop. I test on Chrome and Safari in Ipad and iPhone, it's shows error in the audio element when click button plays audio. With Chrome for Android phone, it's still working but with the first array, not autoplay next audio.

Comment: Hi @blex. Can you help me? I create new question at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50312509/javascript-the-audio-element-listener-event-ended-is-not-working-in-android